# Notification about "I added the info you asked for" comment

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications, deleted-comments

On one hand, comments like "I added the info you asked for" should be deleted, as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349618/).

On the other hand, if they get deleted, the previous commenter who had asked for the info doesn't see the notification anymore. It's not good to give users only a **limited timeframe** to see in their inbox that the info they asked for got added.

A possible solution is to keep the notification that links to the answer, even if the comment gets deleted. Should this solution or another solution or no solution be implemented?

Comment: this kind of looks like duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212981/let-me-view-deleted-questions-i-replied-to

Comment: @mindstormsboi The question you linked is about *reading rights* and *deleted questions*. My question is about *notifications* and *deleted comments*.

Comment: In this case I would suggest that if the original commenter is interested in the update, they can 1. visit the question again 2. follow the question. Both of these will allow them to see the change. Speaking for myself - I sometimes comment that X is missing but I am not invested enough to want a status update. Getting "this was changed, check again" notifications is just useless to me in those cases. I tend to use the follow feature a lot for things I actually am interested in.

Comment: *...the previous commenter who had asked for the info doesn't see the notification anymore...* I've gotten notifications for comments that were subsequently deleted. Is this something that's been changed?

Comment: @BSMP That's how I had understood [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349618/). Am I wrong?

Comment: I honestly have no idea if there’s a time limit on the notification of a deleted comment. I thought notifications stayed until they are dismissed; maybe I’m wrong.

Comment: @BSMP I've definitely seen notifications disappear (almost?) immediately after a comment was deleted. But I've only seen that on comments that the user deleted themselves. The situation where I've encountered that was when I was already looking at a post and see a comment was posted *and* I get a notification. I expand the comment and see it's something addressed to me but the user then immediately deletes the comment (well, not before I've expanded it). Presumably because when they posted they noticed that comment wasn't needed. So, the notification counter disappears.